# Extract a motif in various url strings with regex in ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

I have different type of strings (in fact logs):

```
2022-08-03T16:20:41 - INFO - server.py - 649 - 192.168.1.24,192.168.1.29 - - [03/Aug/2022 16:20:41] "GET /get_customer_by_id/0024-A HTTP/1.0" 200 554 0.007798
2022-08-03T16:20:56 - INFO - utils.py - 10 - GET - http://192.168.1.24/get_customer_by_id/0025-A
2022-08-03T16:21:13 - INFO - utils.py - 10 - POST - http://192.168.1.24/order
```

I want to extract the customer id in each `get_customer_by_id` url. So for the previous example, i'm looking for `0024-A` and `0025-A`

I tried with a regex `\/get_result\/(.+)` but it gives me all the end of line when there is something after the customer id.
You can have a detail of implementation here: https://rubular.com/r/FgBxR1kUyQAYSl

How can i solve this ?
Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Like this? `\bget_customer_by_id\/(\d+)\b` https://regex101.com/r/6v1UQ9/1

Comment: Replace `.` with `\S`. The period `.` matches any character, including whitespace. Seems you only want to match non-whitespace `\S`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you'd be looking for something like `/\/get_customer_by_id\/(\S+)/`. This will grab all non-whitespace characters (stopping before the `HTTP/1.0` on the first line). If you know it's always `dddd-s`, then you could also use something like `/\/get_customer_by_id\/(\d+-\w)/`. Either way, it will be in the first capture group [(link to info on ruby capture groups)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Capturing).